# GET User returns Authorization_IdentityNotFound error

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm building an application that has a simple email-pass login. I want to use the Microsoft Graph to return the profile information of a user that has logged in (I'm not using office365 OAuth right now).

I've set up an action that tries to fetch this user data (i.e given name or profile photo) from an organization I'm part of. I got this error:

> ```
> "line":113,
> "message":"Client error: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}
>            resulted in a 401 Unauthorized response:
> { 
>   "error": {
>     "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
>      "message": "The identity of the calling application (truncated...)"
>   }
> }
> ```

I've set up the application as specified on the Microsoft Graph tutorial ([step 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=2)) and this the code I've written, using the [repository readme](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php):

```php
class MsGraphService implements iAction
{
    protected $accessToken;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'.ENV('MSGRAPH_TENAND_ID').'/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0';
        $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => ENV('MSGRAPH_CLIENT_ID'),
                'client_secret' => ENV('MSGRAHP_CLIENT_SECRET'),
                'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            ],
        ])->getBody()->getContents());
        $this->accessToken = $token->access_token;
    }

    public function execute($data)
    {
        $graph = new Graph();
        $graph->setAccessToken($this->accessToken);
        $user = $graph->createRequest("GET", sprintf("/users/%s",$data['email']))
                      ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                      ->execute();
        return $user->getGivenName();
    }
}
```

The `accesstoken` attribute was caught, so I think the app configuration is ok.

Maybe is an issue about API permissions, specifically: **Application permissions**?

I've also asked about [this on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/issues/230).

Comment: Have you received Admin Consent for the application you've registered? Also, keep in mind that Client Credentials is not typically an appropriate choice for PHP. Client Credentials should _only_ be used on the server, never on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into problems because you are trying to use the AzureAD V1 authentication endpoint.  It is much easier to get the AzureAD v2 endpoint to work with Microsoft Graph.  There are details on how to do it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=3

The main different between V1 and V2 is that you no longer use a `resource` parameter and you use scopes instead to say want you want access to.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I was reading through these tutorial but it was kind of different that I'm looking for, actually the step 3 is valid when a user authorizes the app to connect with his/her cerdentials. What I need is the application by itself could read any user information inside a organization without a signed-in user.
Anyway, I tried to switch the endpoint to get access token to v2, but I get a 400 error :(

Comment: You likely didn't use the correct endpoint. The v2 endpoint is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` not `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?api-version=2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to fetch user related information using the API (no signed-in user) you should ask an administrator for permissions to read that information. In order to set the correct permissions to your application you should:

1. Go to https://portal.azure.com and login
2. Click on **Azure Active Directory**
3. Go to **App Registrations**
4. Select your existing appliaction and click on **View API permissions**
5. Select **+ Add a permission** / **Microsoft Graph** / **Application Permissions** / **User** / **User.Read.All**
6. Ask an administrator for consent

With that, you will be able to fetch users data from your application without a signed-in user.